# Problema de parpadeo al cargar formulario

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que voy cargando diferentes formularios en un panel. Pero al cargarlos me parpadea la pantalla varias veces y es muy molesto. He usado el `DoubleBuffered=true` pero nada.
Estoy pensando en usar directamente paneles pero para el diseño es mas cómodo usar formularios.

```
Private Sub AbrirFormEnPanel(ByVal Formhijo As Object)
        If Me.pnl_Fondo.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            Me.pnl_Fondo.Controls.RemoveAt(0)
        End If
        Dim fh As Form = TryCast(Formhijo, Form)
        fh.TopLevel = False
        fh.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Me.pnl_Fondo.Controls.Add(fh)
        Me.pnl_Fondo.Tag = fh
        fh.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: Le veo muy dificil solución. Es mejor que uses controles de usuario en lugar de formularios.

Answer (score 0):

He descubierto el problema y por tanto la solución.
La escribo por si a alguien le pasa y le puede servir.

En cada uno de los formularios que cargaba había puesto una imagen de fondo y creo que al cargar el formulario y luego tener que redimensionarlo se tenia que pintar varias veces lo que ocasionaba el parpadeo.
Les he quitado a los formularios el fondo y he dejado un color plano y ya no me ocurre.
Gracias de todos modos y espero que os sirva.